# no such table: main.auth_user__old while saving tables in the section area

Tags: python, django

I am following the net ninja tutorial for Django and I ran into this problem in the admin section while saving the tables in the admin section area.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sqlite it may be that an error happened during a migration, see this bug ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182.

Try dropping and recreating your database, delete the database file and run `python manage.py migrate`